# How to use SqlConnection InfoMessage

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this method that calls a stored procedure. My problem is that it does not return a row, but it prints a message. I am trying to capture that print message into a variable. My problem is I have never ever used `InfoMessage` before and I checked it out online and for the life of me I can't seem to understand it. Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
public List<showWhatClass> showWhatMethod(string deviceWhat, int tagWhat, Decimal latit, Decimal longit, int Process, string CallNext, int CallNextVar)
{
    showWhatCell = new List<showWhatClass>();

    try
    {
        using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("iosShowWhat", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeviceId", deviceWhat);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TagId", tagWhat);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Latitude", latit);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Longitude", longit);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Process", Process);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallNext", CallNext);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallNextVar", CallNextVar);

                connection.Open();

                /*SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    showWhatClass item = new showWhatClass();
                    item.CallNext = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    item.CallNextVar = (int)reader.GetValue(1);
                    showWhatCell.Add(item);
                }*/
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }

    return showWhatCell;
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
connection.Open();

connection.InfoMessage += delegate(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    showWhatClass item = new showWhatClass();
    item.CallNext += "\n" + e.Message;
    showWhatCell.Add(item);
};
```

returns nothing.

Comment: What value are you printing ?

Comment: CallNext and CallNextVar

Comment: @MairajAhmad I am trying to print CallNext and CallNextVar

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `output` parameter to get the message from stored procedure and use it in your code.

Add `output` parameter in stored procedure

```
@name varchar(20) output
```

And then set value of this parameter

```
set @name='Mairaj Ahmad Minhas'
```

Now in your code when you call stored procedure add another parameter like this

```
command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 20);
command.Parameters["@name"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

And after you have called the stored procedure do this to get value from this parameter.

```
string name = command.Parameters["@name"].Value.ToString();
```